# How to retrieve all users from Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I am new to asp.net, I have new tasks to retrieve all users from Active Directory. When I tried to retrieve all users from Active Directory I only got one user.

```
private void btngetuser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        searcher.Filter = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "(sAMAccountName={0})", Environment.UserName);
        //SearchResult findUser = searcher.FindOne();

        foreach (SearchResult findUser in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            if (findUser != null)
            {
                DirectoryEntry user = findUser.GetDirectoryEntry();
                string userName = user.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString();
                string Email = user.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
                string Mobile = user.Properties["Mobile"].Value.ToString();
                string Login = user.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();
                string[] rt = new string[] { Login, userName, Email, Mobile };
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rt);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably only got one user because the `SamAccountName` has to be unique among users - so if you search for one particular `SamAccountName`, you'll never get more than one hit ....

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for  UserPrincipal (users)
   UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
       UserPrincipal foundUser = found as UserPrincipal;

       if(foundUser != null)
       { 
            string userName = foundUser.DisplayName;
            string email = foundUser.Email;
            string login = foundUser.SamAccountName;
        }
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Is there any way to order the result by the last name or first name or another criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a filter, right? Why are you expecting that this query filtered by login name would return all users in AD and not exactly what you asked it for?

Comment: Well, yes, you've specified that you want to obtain information on one specific user - namely the currently logged-in user. If you want to get all users in AD, you have to use another filter. There is a description for this task in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9570/Querying-Microsoft-Active-Directory-Using-Microsof) somewhere in the middle of it.