# UserPrincipal EmailAddress is NULL

Tags: c#, active-directory

I wrote code to get a list of users in a specific group in AD, but I'm getting the `emailAddress` property as `NULL`

[image]

Any help please?

```
public List<UserPrincipal> Groups(string grpName)
{
    List<UserPrincipal> users = new List<UserPrincipal>();
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Company", userName: "XXXXXXXX", password: "XXXXXX");

    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher())
    {               
        var sp = new GroupPrincipal(context, grpName);
        searcher.QueryFilter = sp;

        var group = searcher.FindOne() as GroupPrincipal;

        if (group == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Group Name: {0}", grpName);

        foreach (var f in group.GetMembers())
        {
            var principal = f as UserPrincipal;

            if (principal == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(principal.Name))
                continue;

            users.Add(principal);
            //Console.WriteLine("{0}", principal.Name);
        }
    }

    return users;
}
```

Comment: How you are getting the email address?

Comment: principal.EmailAddress

Comment: what about other properties, are you able to get them?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173158/how-to-retrieve-all-users-from-active-directory

Comment: Yes, some of them are populated with values like the Name.

Comment: didn't work ,still returns null

Comment: `EmailAddress` pulls from the `mail` attribute in AD. Does that account actually have the `mail` attribute populated?